# Wrapping Menu Component of Angular material 6

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-directive, angular-material-6

I am wrapping the angular material menu component. I am extending the MatMenuTrigger, MatMenuItem, making them as separate directives and using it in parent component. In the child component(Menu component), i am only using the mat-menu for the getting the reference and in the parent component(Menu-demo component), attaching the menu(which is in child component) to whichever control we want. I should not use button tag inside the child component,so i used ng-content to the get content from the parent.I just want to expose some property to get that reference. Here my question is how to wrap this reference menu, [stackblitzlink](https://stackblitz.com/edit/menu-component1). Please help me out in this,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The menu directive is not necessary. You can expose the child `MatMenu` and reference it as a property of the containing component and use it directly with the `MatMenuTrigger` directive:

menu.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sq-menu',
    templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
})

export class MenuComponent {
   @ViewChild('menu') matMenu: MatMenu;
}
```

menu.component.html:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-menu>
```

Usage:

```
<button mat-raised-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu.matMenu">home</button>
<sq-menu #menu>
    <button mat-button>
        Item1
    </button>
</sq-menu>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/menu-component1-jzaxz7)

Comment: Thanks for the response, here i should not use it as matMenuTriggerFor in the wrapped component, it should be wrapped with some other name example: sqMenuTriggerFor and its value also menu.someMenu not the mat-menu. I need to wrap it  by retaining the same functionality

Comment: Why do something you don't need to? It isn't clear why you need to do that.

Comment: cannot test it, there is an Error: matMenuTriggerFor: must pass in an mat-menu instance.

Comment: @Pier - it works fine if you do it properly - your code is missing the mat-menu - use the code in the stackblitz example in the question, then make the changes.

Comment: @Pier for modern Angular version it should be like this `@ViewChild('menu', {static: true}) matMenu!: MatMenu;`